# How to map a unique item in id column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

label encode a column in pandas with my own series

```
data = [[1,'A'],
        [1,'A'],
        [1,'B'],
        [2,'C']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns = ['id','element'])
df['element'] = le.fit_transform(df['element'])
```

output

```
   id  element
0   1        0
1   2        0
2   3        1
3   4        2
```

Which is fine but i want p append to the string also

```
   id  element
0   1       p0
1   2       p0
2   3       p1
3   4       p2
```

Comment: done thanx for pointing it out

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `scikit-learn` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After geting output dataframe `df`, You can just add at the end:

```
df.element = "p"+(df.element+1).map(str)
```

result:

```
   id  element
0   1        p1
1   2        p1
2   3        p2
3   4        p3
```